# How to solve Django ManyToMany relationship with 2 levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have a structure like this in Django 1.11:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField()

class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    hashtag = models.ManyToManyField(Hashtag)

class Hashtag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now this creates intermediate table post_hashtag, but how can I access all hashtags using **profile.hashtags.all()**?

Comment: `Hashtag.objects.filter(post__profile=my_profile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain these through a filter, like:

```
Hashtag.objects.filter(post__profile=my_profile)
```

so if you want to add that as a property in your `Profile` class for example, you can implement this as:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField()

    @property
    def hashtags(self):
        return Hashtag.objects.filter(post__profile=self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's one way to do it which I already implemented (the only way I found that works), I was wondering if there is a way to actually make it work by calling post.hashtags.all() using some Custom Manger or any other tricky way? It's just that all other objects I want to retrieve use all() method and this one stands out.